# How to update column values with relation of another table

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

How to add sub_cat_list.child_id dynamically from main_cat_list.id using php. below are 2 images of my parent and child table

[image]

[image]

How to add values into sub_cat_list.child_id relative to sub_cat_list=rel_main_cat using php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to use php?
It is possible with one query(if I correctly understood your question).

```
UPDATE sub_cat_list sub
 INNER JOIN main_cat_list main ON main.main_cat_name = sub.rel_main_cat
   SET child_id = main.id
```

Comment: I was glad to help. Good luck in development ;)

Comment: Thank you sir you help me in too much easy and lighter way. thank you.